Issue with Omitting bucket folders from URL
We're experiencing an issue with the Link Manager Configuration for Bucket URLs after updating our Sitecore JSS to version 21.7.1.
Previously, our URLs were structured like this: <mywebsite>/NewsAndEvents/News/China-uses-more-and-more-green-power.
After the update, they now appear as: <mywebsite>/NewsAndEvents/News/2024/06/14/09/03/China-uses-more-and-more-green-power.
The support team clarified that the front-end JSS update should not affect link creation and that this behavior is standard for items in an item bucket, organized by creation date and time. They mentioned our custom MyProject.Environment.Platform.Pipeline.BucketItemUriBuilder class, which previously generated custom URLs without the date-based structure.
We've added custom logging to this class and redeployed it to our DEV environment, but the logs show URLs still follow the date-based structure. The support team suggested the default implementation might be in play and that publishing on the XM Cloud side after the upgrade could have caused this issue.
Has anyone encountered a similar problem or can provide guidance on fixing this?
Thanks in advance!

Already followed this blog, but didn't helped. https://sitecorejunkie.com/2016/05/31/omit-sitecore-bucket-folder-item-names-from-page-item-urls/

I've discovered a solution to the problem we were facing.
we're using a custom config in src\Environment\platform\App_Config\Include\LinkManager.config that contains,
<itemUrlBuilder type="MyProject.Environment.Platform.Pipeline.BucketItemUrlBuilder,MyProject.Environment.Platform"
patch:instead="*[@type='Sitecore.Links.UrlBuilders.ItemUrlBuilder, Sitecore.Kernel']">

The config tries to patch the "itemUrlBuilder" node with the type "Sitecore.Links.UrlBuilders.ItemUrlBuilder, Sitecore.Kernel".
This type was used in the past, but looking at XM Cloud configs, the following type is used instead by default:
<itemUrlBuilder type="Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Multisite.UrlBuilders.ItemUrlBuilder, Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Multisite">

Our custom config file adds a duplicate node instead of patching a default one.
To resolve this, we adjusted our custom config as,
<itemUrlBuilder type="MyProject.Environment.Platform.Pipeline.BucketItemUrlBuilder,MyProject.Environment.Platform"
         patch:instead="*[@type='Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Multisite.UrlBuilders.ItemUrlBuilder, Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Multisite']">

By making this change, we were able to successfully remove the bucket item path from URLs, fixing the issue

First, don't customize the link manager or actually anything on the platform for XM Cloud - its SaaS and Headless and you should do your implementation in your head application, not the platform.
You need to make use of wildcard items and routing in your head application. Create a wildcard item in the tree where you want the pages to be located, then in your Next.js application, create a route that matches and do your item resolution there. You can read the Url and use that to get the item and pass it to the props.
For reference see the Sitecore Accelerate recipe on using Wildcards: https://developers.sitecore.com/learn/accelerate/xm-cloud/implementation/information-architecture/wildcard-pages
